# Drag and drop at any position Angular

Tags: angular, drag, drop

I want to drag and drop all [Drag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgWGL.png) over the html page on a single list. But these **card's will not overlap on each other** and **after reloading the page cards will be seen at new position** (if dragged and dropped). Please show me a solution.
N.B: I have used Angular cdk already on this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you want "order a list"? distributed the elements in a grid? only move the elements? Your elements are all the same size? can be different sizes?

Comment: resizable is not necessary. but drag and drop at anywhere in the page is required. Now i used Angular Gridster. it fulfils my criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular CDK is awesome for one specific case - sorting lists. In case you want to have something more flexible, I'd suggest having a look at 3-rd party libraries, for example -  [Gridster](https://tiberiuzuld.github.io/angular-gridster2/). This could be a solid background for your app in case drag and drop is one of the main features, as usually lib maintainers have already fixed a lot of bugs that you could potentially face if you decide to implement drag and drop functionality from scratch.

In case you want to keep Angular CDK, you have to implement some complicated logic and keep in mind that you should have everything as a set of lists. We wanted to be able to drag and drop elements both vertically & horizontally in our application so we had vertical CDK lists inside one horizontal list. I'd rather don't go this way again if I have to create a new app with D'n'D.

Comment: thank you... i was expecting something like this